How can I print to a pipe in python?
I'm creating a pipe with:
popen = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

and I would like to print to popen.stdin.  The key is that I'd like to print(..., file=popen.stdin) to it, not call write() on it, but popen.stdin is a _io.BufferedWriter which only supports writing bytes, not printing strings.
The reason I cannot just use the write method of popen.stdin is that I need to hand it off to code that doesn't know it's writing to a pipe, so it's printing strings.  I assume I need some sort of file-like thing that takes strings, encodes them, and then writes the bytes to the BufferedWriter.
I assume such a thing exists, but I'm rather new to python.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Add text=True to your subprocess call, so that it uses text instead of binary I/O channels.

also, in general, you could use a io.TextIOWrapper I think

As mentioned, wrapper = io.TextWrapper(popen.stdin) works.

This is a block pipe so stuff you print/write may not be seen by the program until a certain threshold is met or flush is called.
